# React-Joyride: How can I cancel a callback when adding steps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one method that adds steps to joyride through the standard way of adding the steps, then parsing them, then starting the tour. The main reason for using joyride was to guide the user through the different 'pages' in my SPA, but what if the user wants to rewatch the tour for a specific page? When the user finishes a page, they have their progress saved and they move on to the next page, this is performed through the Joyride callback method that gets called when you complete or skip the current set of steps.

I need to make a separate method to add the steps for the individual page and restrict the callback to not reset and/or stop the tour.